# Downloading pics via R Programming

Tags: r, image

I am trying to download the image of from this website listed below via R programming
http://www.ebay.com/itm/2pk-HP-60XL-Ink-Cartridge-Combo-Pack-CC641WN-CC644WN-/271805060791?ssPageName=STRK:MESE:IT

Which package should I use and how should I process it?

Objective: To download the image in this page to a folder 
AND / OR
to find the image URL.

I used

```
url2          <- "http://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/381164104651"
url_content  <- html(url2)
node1 <- html_node(url_content, "#icImg")
```

node1 has the image url, but when I am trying to edit this content I get an error saying it is a non-character element.

Comment: Are you looking for `html_node(url_content, "#icImg") %>% xml_attr("src")`?

Comment: Interesting that the seller of the item on eBay has a name very similar to the OP. I wonder if they anticipated increased traffic?

Comment: No No, Its mine. I have that item for sale. I need to monitor my listing. So, I wonder how to form a database. I need to either download the image or store the image url in a CSV file.

Comment: @Frank: I am unable to understand what you are telling. I am a newbie to this R programming. I use stackoverflow to learn.
I have no intent to increase traffic.

Comment: If you are trying to get the image url, then enter the line of code I suggested or without using the pipe operator: `xml_attr(node1, "src")`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solved my problem
`html_node(url_content, "#icImg") %>% xml_attr("src")`